# Use of CCTexture2D in cocos2dx

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x development. So any one tell me, how can i use CCTexture2D in  cocos2Dx? So that i will use setTexture for CCSprite.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create CCtexture2D by following line :

```
CCTexture2D *texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage(pszFileName);
sprite -> setTexture(texture);
```

I think this may useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

CCImage* ccImageDefault = new CCImage();

```
ccImageDefault->initWithImageFile("defaultImage.png");
```

CCTexture2D* ccTextureDefault= new CCTexture2D();

```
ccTextureDefault->initWithImage(ccImageDefault);
```

CCSprite* spriteUser = CCSprite::create("my.png");

```
    spriteUser->setTexture(ccTexturedefault);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `cocos2d::Sprite` method named `setSpriteFrame(std::string frameName)` in v3.x or `setDisplayFrame(std::string frameName)` in v2.x could do the job better. You should check a look at those two. Hope it help.